# Comparing Events with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working on an iOS app and I'd like to track and compare events.  I started initially with "virtual screen views" and custom dims/mets.  That didn't really sit right with me so I looked into the event logging.

Event logging works a lot better except for one thing; it's a lot harder to get to the information I want.  For later examples, let's consider the following events:

```
Category    Action    Label
--------    ------    -----
Ad          Load      Success
Ad          Load      Success
Ad          Load      Fail
Ad          Load      Success
Ad          Click     Stay
Ad          Click     Leave
```

I've found that I can create a report that filters by `Event Category = Ad` just fine.  I can also add a second dimension Event Action, select Success and Fail, and click Plot Rows.  Then I get a nice visual timeline of my successful loads vs. failed loads compared with (and I would actually prefer not have this line, but it is what it is) total events.  I can even save a shortcut to this report so that I can return to this configuration more easily.

That's well and good, but I'd like to get these data on my dashboard.  I can more or less get what I'm looking for with a pivot table, but not a timeline.  I can also get something visually appealing with a bar graph, but for some reason, the bar colors don't match across the pivot dimensions!

If I use custom dims/mets for the events, I can get exactly what I want but it feels like overkill to duplicate the data just for the sake of getting dashboard views.

Another example is I'd like to compare `Ad - Load - Success` with `Ad - Click` (being the sum of `Ad - Click - Leave` and `Ad - Click - Stay` but I can't find any way of generating that comparison at all with events.  With custom dims/mets, it's no problem.

I did learn that I can send custom dims/mets with events rather than page views so I can get the same data I was before without messing up my page views but, again, it feels redundant to have an *Event Action* dimension that matches my *Event Action* Engagement dimension.

Are there any common effective ways of comparing event data with Google Analytics?  I'm particularly interested in timelines, graphical representations, and dashboard widgets.

Thanks!